# Regex for arrays separated with comma nodejs

Tags: node.js, regex

I have list of codes which are separated by comma, the code contains min of 3 and max of 6 characters including numbers. I have written regex for this. How can I expand my regex to work with 1 or more codes as array or list?

Here is my regex for codes

```
const checkCodes = new RegExp('^[A-Z]+[A-Z0-9]{2,5}$');
```

The above regex works well with single codes

```
codes - "BCD"
```

but not for below line, which I am trying to achieve

```
codes - ["BCD", "VOC123",....1 or more codes]
```

Comment: try to remove the `^` and `$`. They're special characters that indicate the beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string.

Comment: Do you want to match the whole line or all code separately?

Comment: Code seperately, I have function that will take codes one by one present in the list and display them

Comment: So you mean like `new RegExp("\b[A-Z]+[A-Z0-9]{2,5}\b","g");`?

Comment: What do you want as output?

Comment: @Jonas One or more product codes, whatever is passed.

Comment: @Thefourthbird what goes "g" do here?

Comment: That makes it a global match to match all occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const checkCodes = new RegExp('^[A-Z]+[A-Z0-9]{2,5}$');

let input = ["CODE1", "NOT.A.CODE", "CODE42"];

console.log(input.filter(str => checkCodes.test(str)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const checkCodesMulti = /^([A-Z]+[A-Z0-9]{2,5})(?:\s*,\s*([A-Z]+[A-Z0-9]{2,5}))*$/

let input = "BCD, VOC123, ETC";
let array_of_codes = checkCodesMulti.exec(input).splice(1)
```

Comment: Wasn't the input a comma-separated array, not comma-separated string?

Comment: @JonasBerlin, what is ‘comma-separated array’?

Comment: `[ "foo", "bar" ]` I suppose, like was shown in the question